# Skills bar with jQuery and Sass

Tags: jquery, html, sass

I am making a portfolio page and I am trying to include a skills bar that animates the width with jQuery but something is going wrong - nothing happens.

**HTML**

```
<div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="89%">
              <div class="skillbar-title"><span>HTML5</span></div>
              <div class="skillbar-bar"></div>
              <div class="skill-bar-percent">89%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="87%">
              <div class="skillbar-title"><span>CSS3</span></div>
              <div class="skillbar-bar"></div>
              <div class="skill-bar-percent">87%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="58%">
              <div class="skillbar-title"><span>JavaScript</span></div>
              <div class="skillbar-bar"></div>
              <div class="skill-bar-percent">58%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="68%">
              <div class="skillbar-title"><span>jQuery</span></div>
              <div class="skillbar-bar"></div>
              <div class="skill-bar-percent">68%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="73%">
              <div class="skillbar-title"><span>Sass</span></div>
              <div class="skillbar-bar"></div>
              <div class="skill-bar-percent">73%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="82%">
              <div class="skillbar-title"><span>Bootstrap</span></div>
              <div class="skillbar-bar"></div>
              <div class="skill-bar-percent">82%</div>
            </div>
```

**SASS**

```css
.skillbar
  position: relative
  display: block
  margin: 1.4rem auto
  width: 85%
  background: $col-gray
  height: 2.4rem
  border-radius: 3px
  transition: 0.1s linear
  transition-property: width, background-color
.skillbar-title 
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  width: 110px
  font-weight: bold
  font-size: 1rem
  color: #ffffff
  background: $col-darkgray
  border-top-left-radius: 3px
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px
.skillbar-title span 
  display: block
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
  padding: 0 20px
  height: 2.4rem
  line-height: 35px
  text-align: center
  border-top-left-radius: 3px
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px
.skillbar-bar
  height: 2.4rem
  width: 0px
  background: $col-aqua
  border-radius: 3px
.skill-bar-percent 
  position: absolute
  right: 10px
  top: .3rem
  font-size: 1rem
  height: 1.4rem
  line-height: 1.5
  color: $col-light
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.skillbar').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width:$(this).attr('data-percent')
        },4000);
    });
});
```

The div should go from `0px` (defined in `.skillbar-bar`) to the value of `data-percent` (defined in the HTML).

My problem is that absolutely nothing happens when I load the page.

Comment: your examples don't show anything please fix them.

Comment: Can you provide the only needed css code, the sass here is not valid cause things are missing. After that combine everything in one snippet then people can see the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okey in this **[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=1434fa5cfa46563c1902c0330d60f5e7)**. Please check out and tell us specificly whats going wrong?

Comment: Yeah, basically it does not do that... when I load the page, the width stays at 0px. So is SASS the problem or is it something else?

Comment: shoukd you use SASS? CSS doesnt do the same?

Comment: Yeah, well Sass does not use brackets nor semi-colons but it does compile into the same .css file. But I am not sure what the real problem is here, it just does not work.

Comment: When it doesnt work press f12 and check if there is any error in the debugger.

Comment: That was actually the problem. Thank you, so stupid of me

Comment: what was the mistake?

Comment: The script tag with the jQuery CDN was not working properly. The console threw errors like .find, .animate, $(...) ... are not functions, so I checked what would happen if I change the jQuery link in the html.

Answer (score 0):

After all, it turned out it was a bad jQuery CND link. I console.log-ed separate elements of the jQuery snippet but everything worked fine so I did not bother checking the console. Sorry for the unnecessary question and thank you for your help!